# Website not running on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angularjs

I use data from localhost and REST API in my website. My website run properly on IE but in Chrome and Firefox CROS origin related problem occurs. I use Angular.js to create website. Please suggest how to solve these problem.

Comment: Please provide some more information so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome above problem is solved by adding "allow cross origin *" extension.